# How to open a PHP socket server on my Jelastic environment? Issue Binding

Tags: php, sockets, jelastic

I have a `Jelastic` environment which runs a `PHP` `socket` server that receives messages from GPS devices (which communicate via GPRS) and stores what it receives. I'm using the SocketServer.class.php class created by Navarr Barnier ([link here](https://gist.github.com/navarr/459321)). It's a pretty simple application as you can see:

```
<?php
require_once("SocketServer.class.php");
$server = new SocketServer("<server address>",20490);
$server->max_clients = 10;
$server->hook("CONNECT","handle_connect");
$server->hook("INPUT","handle_input");
$GLOBALS['conexao'] = mysql_connect('<mysql_address>', 'root', '<mysql_password>');
$GLOBALS['selected'] = mysql_select_db('<database>',$GLOBALS['conexao']);
$server->infinite_loop();

function handle_connect($server,$client,$input)
{
    SocketServer::socket_write_smart($client->socket,"OK!");
}
function handle_input($server,$client,$input)
{
  //echo "\nInput = ".$input;
  //$query = "INSERT INTO `messages`(`message`) VALUES (\"".$input."\")";
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `messages`(`message`) VALUES ('".$input."')");
}
```

This code gives Issue Binding as the output, i.e it cannot create a socket at given IP:port and other IP:ports.

Actually, I've tried it all:

```
$server = new SocketServer("localhost",20490);
$server = new SocketServer("127.0.0.1",20490);
$server = new SocketServer("0.0.0.0",20490);
$server = new SocketServer("0",20490);
$server = new SocketServer("<server_dns>",20490);
$server = new SocketServer("<server_public_ip>",20490);
```

And more... All gives "Issue Binding".
Any ideas on how to setup this basic socket server?

Comment: Can you add the error message?

Comment: The error message is "Issue Binding.", it means it could not bind to socket.

Comment: It comes from this line at the SocketServer.class.php: `socket_bind($this->master_socket,$this->config["ip"],$this->config["port"]) or die("Issue Binding");`

Comment: Are you sure that is all that its giving? Is there any warning or anything else?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I forgot about the apache logs. From all the IP addresses I used, the warnings goes from: If I use the dns or the public ip address, it says: `PHP Warning:  socket_bind(): unable to bind address [98]: Address already in use in /var/www/webroot/ROOT/SocketServer.class.php on line 53`.. other ones might give `PHP Warning:  socket_bind(): unable to bind address [13]: Permission denied in /var/www/webroot/ROOT/SocketServer.class.php on line 53` or `PHP Warning:  socket_bind(): unable to bind address [99]: Cannot assign requested address in /var/www/webroot/ROOT/...comment too long`

Comment: Line 53 is the `socket_bind($this->master_socket,$this->config["ip"],$this->config["port"]) or die("Issue Binding");` line.

Comment: Do you have public IP enabled on your web server? You can't use sockets via the Jelastic resolver (i.e. public IP disabled)

Comment: Hi Damien. I think I do, at least it shows a Public IP at my Apache module. I tried using the Apache public IP as the address at the socket server, but it didn't work. Any other thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: Try another port, similar by default e.g. 8001 or 8040.